# XCode 15.0 build error: unable to initiate PIF transfer session (operation in progress?)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile, cocoapods

## Build service could not create build operation: unknown error while handling message: MsgHandlingError(message: "unable to initiate PIF transfer session (operation in progress?)")

Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d) (was happening on 14 as well)

Whenever I switch from one iOS project to another and try to build the app or archive, I get this error.

**What solves this error:**

1. Closing XCode,
2. Removing DerivedData
3. Relaunching XCode:

```bash
# clearing DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

All questions on StackOverflow give the patch fix of restarting XCode clearing cache, but what is exactly the cause of this issue? And how can we solve it permanently?

Even though I have added aliases inside zsh profile to quickly clear XCode's cache, it's still a bit annoying having to do this iteration every time I need to open a project.

Comment: Did you find any solution so far ?

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon I haven't had time the past week, I was loaded with a lot of work. I will try to check it out today or tomorrow to see if I can find a permanent  solution for it

Comment: at the end Restarting mac works for me ...

Comment: For me, killing the process of XCode and clearing derived data works as a temporary solution. I tried restarting the mac as well, but the issue always comes back. Will try to see if I can find any solution which would solve this once and for all.

Comment: @NuttyJackJ did you find any permanent solution for this

Comment: @Sagar Unfortunately no, however, I have noticed that this error is not happening to me as frequent as before. I have updated XCode to Version 15.0.1 (15A507).
It still happens but in very rare occasions.